# Listctrl SetItemData as String

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

I am not understanding why I can't use a string for SetItemData in a ListCtrl. I use it for a CustomTreeControl and it works fine. I don't get it.

"TypeError: ListCtrl.SetItemData(): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'"

```
list_row = self.lc_results.GetItemCount()
self.lc_results.SetItemData(list_row, item.split(':')[1])
```

Comment: I think it's expecting a `ListItem` you're giving it a count integer and a string.

Comment: I thought I posted more code than this. I will update when I get home. It is looping through a list, appending, and then adding the item data. I tested it by placing an integer, and it works just fine.